# Very Wierd Output, for my text extraction program

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, python-imaging-library, python-tesseract

This is my Program, Text Extraction from Image program:

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
import os
from os.path import join
import sys
con_1 = True
store_1 = []
store_2 = []
store_3 = []
con_1 = True
print("Welcome to my Text Extraction from Image Program. Here you can extract text from any image.")
while con_1:
    image_name = input("Enter your image's name:")
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/home/"):
        if image_name in files:
           found = join(root, image_name)
           store_1.append(found)
    if len(store_1) == 0:
       ask_1 = str(input("Your image was not found. Do you want to try again(Y/n)?:"))
       if ask_1 == "Y" or ask_1 == "y":
          con_1 = True
       elif ask_1 == "N" or ask_1 == "n":
          con_1 = False
       else:
          print("Your input is out of bounds. Please try again.")
    else:
        print("Your image was successfully found.")
        image_open = Image.open(found)
        image_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image_open)
        print(image_text)
        break
```

This is the image I am testing it on:
[image]

And this is the most weirdest output I have ever seen:

```
‘Understanding how computer memory
ia tire terrae tec
programming lan
```

This is another image I am testing it on: [image]

And another really weird output:

```
Sesh chee nia ec Hiok pc



RU hun oe
mete een
machines work while still being easy to learn.
```

I have never seen my program giving me such off-target and weird outputs. I have absolutely no idea how this is happening. I would very much like to know how to fix it as well as why my program is malfunctioning.